# SQL Server Delete - Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I have got two tables in SQL Server 2005:

- USER Table: information about user and so on.
- COUNTRY Table : Holds list of whole countries on the world.
- USER_COUNTRY Table: Which matches, which user has visited which county.
  It holds, UserID and CountryID.

For example, USER_COUNTRY table looks like this:

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| ID | UserID | CountryID |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |        34 |
|  2 |      1 |         5 |
|  3 |      2 |        17 |
|  4 |      2 |        12 |
|  5 |      2 |        21 |
|  6 |      3 |        19 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

**My question is that**: When a user is deleted in USER table, how can I make associated records in USER_COUNTRY table deleted directly. Maybe, by using Foreign Key Constaint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could set your foreign key relationship Delete rule to Cascade.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a foreign key in `USER_COUNTRY` that points to `USER.UserID` and set cascaded deletion:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_COUNTRY (
    ...
    CONSTRAINT USER_COUNTRY_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
        REFERENCES USER(UserID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Your FK constraint actually points to the COUNTRY table and would wipe out the country info.......

Answer (score 0):

I guess CASCADE is your only option. But do you really want to hard delete records like this? Context: I'm a data fiend.